# Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Command\Result::getBody()

Tags: php, drupal, httpclient, guzzle, drupal-9

I am trying to get a response in Drupal from an outside API in json format. I am using HTTP Client Manager Drupal module.
Right now I can only get response in stdClass Object format in Array and all the response key values are missing.

My original code:

```
public function findPosts() {
    $client = $this->getClient();
    $params = array('client_Id' => "12345",
    "client_Secret" => "42452454",
    "scope" => "read");

      $response = $client->FindPosts($params);

      dpm($response);

    return ['#markup' => $response];
  }
```

Outputs the code below. What I need it too look like is [access_token] => eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsIn, [type] => bearer, etc.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => GuzzleHttp\Command\Result
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiIsIn
            [1] => bearer
            [2] => 3600
            [3] => 2022-11-09T10:48:47+00:00
            [4] => read
            [5] => MwA1ADkAZAA0AGIAZAA4AC0AOQAzADcA
            [6] => 86400
            [7] => 2022-11-10T09:48:47+00:00
        )

)
```

When I try $response->getBody() or $response->getContent(), or any other response method it returns the error below.

```
Error: Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Command\Result::getBody() in Drupal\http_client_manager_example\Controller\ExampleController->findPosts() (line 92 of modules/contrib/http_client_manager/modules/http_client_manager_example/src/Controller/ExampleController.php).
Drupal\http_client_manager_example\Controller\ExampleController->findPosts()
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 169)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 81)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 49)
Asm89\Stack\Cors->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 38)
Drupal\webprofiler\StackMiddleware\WebprofilerMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 709)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Comment: You seem to utilize guzzle/command, pls. refer to https://github.com/guzzle/command to see how it works

Comment: Check out the Drupal module issue tracker. Here's an issue about `getBody()` undefined method: https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client_manager/issues/2996559

Comment: @bwaindwain thank you, toArray() method definitely works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bwaindwain [mentioned](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_client_manager/issues/2996559) `toArray()` method works instead of `getBody()`.

`toArray()` method works wells with responses in format:

```
[
    {
      "token": "4354iojegdjss"
    }
]
```

However, with this response format all keys still disappear:

```
 {
      "token": "4354iojegdjss"
 }
```

My fix for this issue is to manually add `responseModel` in `src/api/resources/posts.json` this way:

```
{
  "operations": {
    "GetToken": {
      "httpMethod": "POST",
      "uri": "token",
      "summary": "Get token",
      },
      "responseModel": "Token"
  }
}

 "models": {
    "Token": {
      "type": "object",
      "location": "json",
      "properties": {
        "token": {
          "location": "json",
          "type": "string"
        }
       }
    }
 }
```

If somebody knows a better fix, please, comment.